# WebRequest.BeginGetResponse -"AsyncCallback" target on non void method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I need to call HttpWebRequest asynchronously, the problem is that BeginGetResponse method has as its first parameter AsyncCallback which targets method with void signature.

```
    WebRequest _webRequest;

    private void StartWebRequest()
    {
        _webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), null);
    }
```

I need have as target method with Stream return type. Something like this:

```
    private Stream FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
       var response= _webRequest.EndGetResponse(result);

       using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
       {
           Byte[] buffer = new Byte[response.ContentLength];
           int offset = 0, actuallyRead = 0;
           do
           {
               actuallyRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset, buffer.Length - offset);
               offset += actuallyRead;
           }
           while (actuallyRead > 0);
           return new MemoryStream(buffer);
       }
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, basically. That can't be your callback. Moreover, it would be pointless for it to *be* your callback, because nothing could actually use the returned stream. What are you intending to happen with the stream once the callback has fired?

It's easy enough to create a callback which just calls your `FinishWebRequest` method, but that would discard the stream, leaving you no better off...

(Personally I wouldn't rely on ContentLength by the way - it's not always set. I'd just maintain a small buffer which you read into and then write straight into the memory stream. If you're using .NET 4 you can use the new [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) method to make life easier. Also, `WebResponse` implements `IDisposable` so you should have a `using` statement for that too.)